# Azure Remote Debugging - Conexões Simultâneas

Tags: microsoft-azure

Estou utilizando o Azure Remote Debugging e me surgiu a seguinte dúvida. Na camada Free, Shared ou Basic, quantas conexões simultâneas posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Concurrent debugger connections per application:

- **Free:** 1
- **Shared:** 1
- **Basic:** 1
- **Standard:** 5
- **Premium:** 5

Veja mais na documentação sobre [Limites do Serviço de Aplicativo do Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits).

Comment: Muito obrigado!!